# Rename an SVN changelist

Tags: svn, changelist

I have files in a changelist in SVN.

I would like to rename that changelist, while keeping the files in it.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
svn changelist -R <new_name> . --changelist <old_name>
```

Explanation:

- what this does is move files to the new checklist
- the way it operates is it puts all files in `.`, thanks to the `-R` option, filtered by the `--changelist` option